# Web development and where to start?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, laravel

I've watched many web development videos on youtube and heard many different things, from picking up a certain language and practicing it, to picking up a framework like "Ruby on Rails" etc.

The thing that worries me the most however, is that everything is new to me, when I see an abbreviation of something that keeps being mentioned(things like MVC, OOP, etc.) and I google it, I end up with 10 more new abbreviations and it keeps going.

So I was wondering, for a person who wants to get into building websites/web apps, where should I start?
Or to make this little cry for help easier to answer:

- What do you think about a total beginner starting with Ruby on Rails?
- Should I read a book/blog/watch a video on computer science 101 before getting into anything specific?
- I'd also be more than happy if you could suggest any good reading/video material to check out concerning any of the questions above.
- My friend told me to learn how websites/servers work, learn about cookies, MySQL and preferably pick Laravel over Ruby on Rails(altho from what I've read it seems like Rails might be a more beginner friendly choice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The thing that worries me the most however, is that everything is new to me, when I see an abbreviation of something that keeps being mentioned(things like MVC, OOP, etc.) and I google it, I end up with 10 more new abbreviations and it keeps going.

If you **do not have programming experience** at all, you **can't start learning Ruby on Rails**. You first need to learn programming, then learn at least the basics of Ruby and only then start with Rails.

Start learning things in this order:

- HTML
- CSS
- JavaScript
- Learn how to use CSS framework (Try Bootstrap)
- Learn how to use JavaScript library (Try jQuery)
- Learn a server side language (Try Ruby)
- Learn how to use Ruby framework (Try Rails)

... and keep practicing! The more you practice, the more you get into trouble, the more you understand how things work.

> I'd also be more than happy if you could suggest any good reading/video material to check out concerning any of the questions above.

You can start in [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) - a beginner friendly website to learn basics of HTML, CSS & JS.

There's an awesome book on programming - [Learn to Program](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/ltp2/learn-to-program-2nd-edition) that provides an introduction to programming using Ruby.

> What do you think about a total beginner starting with Ruby on Rails?

You should not start learning Rails as you do not have any prior knowledge of programming as well as Ruby. Rails is no more a beginners thing, it's a sharp knife, not recommended for beginners. The knowledge required to be a nice web developer is quite extensive, so start with little but stay consistent. It will take time but will pay you the debt.

Comment: I completely understand what you're saying. I'm not looking to rush anywhere, atm I'm just trying to get comfortable with all the terms, get more familiar with the basics, but I'm trying to plan out my future studies. thank you for the comment :)

Comment: I have updated my answer, hope it will help. :)

Comment: thank you very much, everyone here has been very helpful and insightful :)

Comment: @7stud, Ruby is simple and easy when you start learning it, but to understand how Rspec works, you have to have good grasp over the language. I would suggest you to finish at least The book of Ruby ( http://www.amazon.com/The-Book-Ruby-Hands-On-Adventurous/dp/1593272944 ). Then you will have better understanding of Ruby as well as other Ruby gems.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that web programming takes many years of experience with:

1. html
2. css
3. javascript
4. A server side language like: ruby, python, perl, java, etc
5. databases, e.g. sqlite, mysql/mariadb

So what you are really saying is, "I want to web program NOW!", and it just isn't possible.

However, you can try this tutorial:

https://www.railstutorial.org/

which, like all rails tutorials, just has you copy a bunch of stuff, and at the end of it--if you make it--you will have a working website.  It may also give you some ideas of where you want to concentrate any further studies.

Comment: I might have exaggerated with the level of my newbieness, I'm sorry. While I don't have years of experiance with any of these, I'm not completely unfamiliar with some of the things you've mentioned. I have the basics of html and css down, I understand how js works, but out of all of these I'm most familiar with python(I've completed a coursera course on it).
Also- thank you for the link, I'll definitely check it out :)

Comment: @ssnewbie93, If you are already familiar with python, then you should learn `django`, which is python's version of ruby on rails.  Unfortunately, there are no current books on django, but the django website has a tutorial, and there is another tutorial called Tango with Django.  Doing both of those tutorials will get you started.

Comment: I thought about that aswell, but I've found much less info about it compared to Ruby on Rails. I'm not looking for anything to rush through, my main concern atm is that I start with something beginner friendly, learn the web-dev lingo and try to take it slow and actually get good at it.

Comment: @ssnewbie93, You've got a point there.  I suggest you do this: Start the rails tutorial I linked to--it is updated every year, and a new version just came out, whose purpose was to make everything easier.  One of the early chapters goes over some basic ruby.  At some point, if you find you are lost, then stop and buy a beginning ruby book, and study that for awhile, then go back to the tutorial.

Comment: ok man, I'll definitely check it out. Also, I really appreciate you taking the time and respond in such a helpfull manner :)

Comment: @ssnewbie93, Sure.  Just to clarify: at the link, there is a picture of the book, and under the pictures is a link to read the tutorial online for free.  I actually prefer having a book, so I can scribble stuff in the margins, but you can read the book online for free if that suits you.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend is correct. First of all, you should learn about cookies, SQL, JavaScript, CSS and pick a platform for development(like Ruby on rails or PHP or anything).

If yo go with Ruby on Rails, try to learn [Michael Hartl's Book](https://www.railstutorial.org/book). Its gives a good start on Ruby on Rails. And there are many open source available to learn Ruby on Rails.

My suggestion is go with **Ruby on Rails**. Because, its really a developer friendly environment to build web applications.

**For Ruby on Rails**
[Railscast](http://railscasts.com)
[Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have stated that you find programming interesting, I am assuming that you know programming at a basic level.

At the stage you are on, you don't need to worry about terms like MVC, OOP, Cookies etc. The only acronym you need is KISS(Keep it simple Sam!)

Now towards your questions,

- In my Computer science degree I only had exposure to languages like C++ and Java(not web, just desktop programming, like algorithms and stuff). When I started my job, I was asked to learn RoR, and let me tell you, the learning process had very less correlation with my College courses(basic programming), even ruby is very different from C++ and Java. RoR is simple, but only for people who actually have some experience in web development. If you want to hard and develop your concepts, RoR is not a very good choice.
- I advise that you keep it simple. Learn basic HTML, Javascript, and php to get the flavor of web development. [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) is a great place to start. Again, RoR is simple, but NOT for a beginner.
- Get the basic concepts of how-websites-work, sessions, cookies but don't get too stuck in this stuff, always remember, tuts and text books never make you a programmer, only programming does.

Comment: Well I'm not sure how basic you mean, but I think I do :) I like that you mentioned php because all that I've read/heard about it so far is that it's a disguisting language, and it's because of that that I didn't even consider it. And I agree, I think REALLY understanding the concept of how-websites-work is something I should focus on right now.

Comment: Your friends are right, php does get messy in large enterprise applications where scalability and code maintenance is on top priority, but a newbie developer trying to setup a simple blog, it is not even a concern :) Plus, php has possibly the highest scope for freelancing on the internet *wink wink*

Answer (score 0):

I would checkout coding on khanacademy.com, the have some good intro computer science tutorials.  If you get through them and still like coding.  Can review stanford's CS 101 on iTunes university for free: http://online.stanford.edu/courses/topic/4

Ruby on Rails is a good place to start for web development along with a client side framework like ember.js, angular js, or react JS -- can just pick one and work through examples.